# Remote WMI calls to Windows Server 2008 R2 consistently erroring first try (0x800706BF) then working second try

Tags: c++, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2

The first time I ran [this example C++ code from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for getting WMI data from a remote computer, it worked fine.  It also worked for a coworker with the same configuration as me: **Windows Server 2008 R2 Virtual Machine** (a domain controller) as the remote machine; **Windows 7 host machine** (in a different domain) as the client making the calls.

However, at some point, the code stopped working.  A brief overview of the code: It prompts for credentials, then connects to the remote server, then queries for its OS info with the WQL line `Select * from win32_operatingsystem`, then retrieves the returned OS object, then asks for the object representing the OS's name and the object representing the free memory on the machine, printing this information to the console.  It currently errors upon the first `IEnumWbemClassObject::Next` call, which should retrieve the OS object.

The code I am currently working with is a slightly-adapted version of the example code linked above.   Here is the .cpp in its entirety (with some commented-out blocks of code removed):

```c
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#define UNICODE
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "credui.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")
#include <wincred.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

// Macro for cleanup (changed to exit to imitate original code more closely)
#define EXIT(x) { ret = x; goto out; }

// Entry point:
int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HRESULT hres;
    int ret = 0;

    // Initialize COM
    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        EXIT(1);
    }

    // Set general COM security levels
    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY,    // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        EXIT(1);
    }

    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI 
    IWbemLocator* pLoc = NULL;
    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, 
        (LPVOID*)&pLoc); 

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object." << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        EXIT(1);
    }

    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method...
    IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;

    // First, prompt for the user name and password for the remote computer
    CREDUI_INFO cui;
    bool useToken = false;
    bool useNTLM = true;
    wchar_t pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1] = {0};
    wchar_t pszPwd[CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1] = {0};
    wchar_t pszDomain[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1];
    wchar_t pszUserName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1];
    wchar_t pszAuthority[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1];
    BOOL fSave;
    DWORD dwErr;

    memset(&cui,0,sizeof(CREDUI_INFO));
    cui.cbSize = sizeof(CREDUI_INFO);
    cui.hwndParent = NULL;

    cui.pszMessageText = TEXT("Press cancel to use process token");
    cui.pszCaptionText = TEXT("Enter Account Information");
    cui.hbmBanner = NULL;
    fSave = FALSE;

    dwErr = CredUIPromptForCredentials( 
        &cui,                             // CREDUI_INFO structure
        TEXT(""),                         // Target for credentials
        NULL,                             // Reserved
        0,                                // Reason
        pszName,                          // User name
        CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1,     // Max number for user name
        pszPwd,                           // Password
        CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1,     // Max number for password
        &fSave,                           // State of save check box
        CREDUI_FLAGS_GENERIC_CREDENTIALS |// flags
        CREDUI_FLAGS_ALWAYS_SHOW_UI |
        CREDUI_FLAGS_DO_NOT_PERSIST);  

    if (ERROR_CANCELLED == dwErr)
    {
        useToken = true;
    }
    else if (dwErr)
    {
        cout << "Did not get credentials: " << dwErr << endl;
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        EXIT(1);  
    }

    if (!useNTLM)
    {
        cout << "not using NTLM" << endl;
        StringCchPrintf(pszAuthority, CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1, L"kERBEROS: %s", L"serverdude");
    }

    // Connect to the remote root\cimv2 namespace and obtain pointer pSvc to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"\\\\serverdude\\root\\cimv2"),
        _bstr_t(useToken?NULL:pszName),    // User name
        _bstr_t(useToken?NULL:pszPwd),     // User password
        NULL,                              // Locale             
        NULL,                              // Security flags
        _bstr_t(useNTLM?NULL:pszAuthority),// Authority        
        NULL,                              // Context object
        &pSvc                              // IWbemServices proxy
        );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        EXIT(1);
    }
    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;

    // Create COAUTHIDENTITY that can be used for setting security on proxy
    COAUTHIDENTITY* userAcct = NULL;
    COAUTHIDENTITY authIdent;

    if (!useToken)
    {
        memset(&authIdent, 0, sizeof(COAUTHIDENTITY));
        authIdent.PasswordLength = wcslen (pszPwd);
        authIdent.Password = (USHORT*)pszPwd;

        LPWSTR slash = wcschr (pszName, L'\\');
        if (NULL == slash)
        {
            cout << "Could not create Auth identity. No domain specified.\n";
            pSvc->Release();
            pLoc->Release();
            CoUninitialize();
            EXIT(1);
        }

        StringCchCopy(pszUserName, CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1, slash+1);
        authIdent.User = (USHORT*)pszUserName;
        authIdent.UserLength = wcslen(pszUserName);

        StringCchCopyN(pszDomain, CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1, pszName, slash - pszName);
        authIdent.Domain = (USHORT*)pszDomain;
        authIdent.DomainLength = slash - pszName;
        authIdent.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;

        userAcct = &authIdent;
    }

    // Set security levels on a WMI connection
    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
       pSvc,                           // Indicates the proxy to set
       RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
       RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
       COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name 
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
       userAcct,                       // client identity
       EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        EXIT(1);
    }

    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI...
    // Get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnum = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnum);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for operating system name failed." << " Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        EXIT(1);
    }

    // Secure the enumerator proxy
    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pEnum,                          // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
        COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        userAcct,                       // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities 
        );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket on enumerator. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        pEnum->Release();
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        EXIT(1);
    }

    // Erase credentials from memory.
    SecureZeroMemory(pszName, sizeof(pszName));
    SecureZeroMemory(pszPwd, sizeof(pszPwd));
    SecureZeroMemory(pszUserName, sizeof(pszUserName));
    SecureZeroMemory(pszDomain, sizeof(pszDomain));

    // Get the data from the OS query
    IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnum)
    {
        // DEBUG:
        cout << "beginning of loop..." << endl;

        // Get the result of the query
        HRESULT hr = pEnum->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);  

        // DEBUG:
        cout << "IEnumWbemClassObject::Next returned 0x" << hex << hr << endl;

        // PATCH: NOT SURE WHY IT WORKS
        if (0 == uReturn)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Get the value of the Name property
        VARIANT vtProp;
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            cout << "Could not get OS name. Error code = 0x" << hex << hr << endl;
            EXIT(1);
        }

        // Display OS name info
        wcout << "\tOS Name : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;

        // Get the value of the FreePhysicalMemory property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"FreePhysicalMemory", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            cout << "Could not get free physical memory. Error code = 0x" << hex << hr << endl;
            EXIT(1);
        }

        // Display free memory info
        wcout << "\tFree physical memory (in kilobytes): " << vtProp.uintVal << endl;

        VariantClear(&vtProp);
        pclsObj->Release();
        pclsObj = NULL;

        // KEEP THIS ONLY IF USING PATCH SOLN
        break;
    }

    // Clean up
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnum->Release();
    if (pclsObj) 
    { 
        pclsObj->Release(); 
    }
    CoUninitialize(); 

out:
    system("pause");
    return ret;
}
```

The output to the console is:

```
Connected to ROOT\CIMV2 WMI namespace
beginning of loop...
IEnumWbemClassObject::Next returned 0x800706bf
beginning of loop...
IEnumWbemClassObject::Next returned 0x0
        OS Name : Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter |C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1
        Free physical memory (in kilobytes): 8050116
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The only significant change to the code is the loop at the end.  The MSDN example does not check for an error but instead breaks out of the loop if `EnumWbemClassObject::Next` sets the `puReturned` parameter to 0 ([indicating 0 objects returned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the 1 requested).  Instead, I display the result but don't act on it, try the loop again if `uResult` is 0, and only break out of the loop when it doesn't.  This is obviously a hacky solution that could result in an infinite loop if the code worked properly.  It's also worth noting that at one point when I was experimenting with the loop, I got one of those weird access violations: the program threw the exception at a certain line, but when I changed the *next* line the problem went away.  This makes me think there might be something weird going on with memory corruption.

Here's the weirder part: when I run **WBEMtest.exe** (a Windows-provided GUI for running WMI commands, local or remote), **my query *also* only works on the second try**.  Like my code, it returns `Error 0x800706bf: The remote procedure call failed and did not execute` on the first try.

Out of curiosity, I logged the WMI activity using Event Logging.  I couldn't glean much from the results (other than the fact that different stuff is happening between my code and WBEMtest.exe) but here they are anyway:

*From a run of my code:*

```
Level   Date and Time   Source  Event ID    Task Category
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6350; OperationId = 6350; Operation = IWbemServices::Connect; ClientMachine = MSJOHNSON-THINK; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 26304; NamespaceName = \\serverdude\root\cimv2
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6352; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem; ClientMachine = MSJOHNSON-THINK; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 26304; NamespaceName = \\.\root\cimv2
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6353; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - Select * from __ClassProviderRegistration; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6354; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - __Win32Provider.Name=""WmiPerfClass""; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6354
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6355; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name=""WmiPerfClass""}; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6353
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6356; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - __Win32Provider.Name=""CIMWin32""; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6356
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6357; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name=""CIMWin32""}; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6355
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6357
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6358; OperationId = 6358; Operation = IWbemServices::Connect; ClientMachine = WIN-T53A1FADTFB; User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE; ClientProcessId = 3000; NamespaceName = Root
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6358
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6359; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name=""CIMWin32""}; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6359
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6360; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - Win32_OperatingSystem; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6360
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6361; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - __Win32Provider.Name=""CIMWin32""; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6361
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6362; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name=""CIMWin32""}; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6362
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  2   None    ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 6351; Operation = Provider::CreateInstanceEnum - Win32_OperatingSystem; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6363; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - SELECT __RELPATH FROM Win32_Process; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6364; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - __Win32Provider.Name=""CIMWin32""; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6364
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6365; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name=""CIMWin32""}; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6365
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6366; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - Win32_Process; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6366
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6367; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - __Win32Provider.Name=""CIMWin32""; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6367
Information 12/6/2012 12:22:03 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6351; OperationId = 6368; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name=""CIMWin32""}; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName =
```

*From a run of WBEMtest.exe:*

```
Level   Date and Time   Source  Event ID    Task Category
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:41 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6373; OperationId = 6373; Operation = IWbemServices::Connect; ClientMachine = MSJOHNSON-THINK; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 26004; NamespaceName = \\serverdude\root\cimv2
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6374; OperationId = 6375; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - select * from win32_operatingsystem; ClientMachine = MSJOHNSON-THINK; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 26004; NamespaceName = \\.\root\cimv2
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6374; OperationId = 6376; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - Select * from __ClassProviderRegistration; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6374; OperationId = 6377; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - __Win32Provider.Name=""WmiPerfClass""; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6377
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    "GroupOperationId = 6374; OperationId = 6378; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - references of {__Win32Provider.Name=""WmiPerfClass""}; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2"
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6376
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6378
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6374; OperationId = 6379; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - win32_operatingsystem; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  3   None    Stop OperationId = 6379
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  2   None    ProviderInfo for GroupOperationId = 6374; Operation = Provider::CreateInstanceEnum - Win32_OperatingSystem; ProviderName = CIMWin32; ProviderGuid = {d63a5850-8f16-11cf-9f47-00aa00bf345c}; Path = %systemroot%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.dll
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6374; OperationId = 6380; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - SELECT __RELPATH FROM Win32_Process; ClientMachine = Local; User = CORP\Administrator; ClientProcessId = 0; NamespaceName = \\.\root\CIMV2
Information 12/6/2012 12:29:52 PM   Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity  1   None    GroupOperationId = 6374; OperationId = 6381; Operation = Start IWbemServices::GetObject - Win32_Process; ClientMachine = Local; User
```

So, yeah, I'm at a total loss.  Can anyone figure out what's going on?  I've seen reports of others seeing inconsistent WMI behavior between machines in similar situations (e.g. the question here called *WMI query for Win32_BaseBoard returns no results*--can't link because of the two-hyperlink max for new users), but I've never seen a satisfactory explanation.  BTW, I started fresh with a new VM and still had this problem (although every once in a while WBEMtest.exe didn't error out on the first try).

Comment: How did the VM get created? From clone, sysprep, or from DVD? If cloned, then try creating one from scratch, like using the DVD or ISO of Win2008. If from DVD/ISO, then I suggest trying an OS like Win7 from ISO. If both already tried, then try moving the VM to another host. If the host isn't fast enough (CPU, RAM, NIC, HD, etc.) then it can drop initial connections and be ready for next. Hope this makes sense...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Lizz.  I got it from a CD--but a coworker who used the same one doesn't have this problem.  We're currently setting up a new set of VMs for testing, which may shed some light on the situation.  It's been a month and I'm still using my ugly patch solution!

Comment: Just querried 0x800706bf and got this link showing an MS Win2003 (Win2008 also might be applicable) hotfix is available if you call: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960007. Basically, if you send a "burst load" request using lots of threads if could bomb on you. Sounds familiar to what you describe. I still recommend setting up on a different VM host if possible. Try just issuing the call *from* the buggy host (ie, not from a different host). Keep us posted! :)

Comment: Better yet, someone has a near identical issue to yours: http://thwack.solarwinds.com/thread/40276. Seems Win2008 has same issue as Win2003, only a patch hasn't yet been issued. This thread details their method to track the "burst", and what they changed in their process to change how they call the data needed from using WMI to RPC. Worth a look.. I would even suggest creating a SolarWindws forum account and posting to it when you have info to add. :)

Comment: Thanks so much for digging these up!  The problem can't be burst loads, unless something _really_ crazy is going on, because I'm only sending one request from one thread, but I can experiment with the hotfixes on that page anyway.  Contacting Msoft is also a good idea--I'll probably wait until after I get my MSDN license so I get better/quicker support.  And I will definitely report back here and on solarwinds if/when I figure this out! :)

Comment: I'm wrestling with a WMI error now; ConnectServer is killing me! It's one of the most painful things I've yet encountered - and finnicky. Might want to verify only one thread is being sent; use TCPView from SysInternals to check.

Comment: Any luck with solving this yet?

Comment: Sigh, nope.  By now, for unrelated reasons, we've moved our queries to local ones (i.e. sending a deployable to the target box and connecting to the WMI server locally).  I think this will forever be a mystery of Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Wish it could have been solved but alas, Microsoft sometimes leaves us with mysteries. Good luck!